# connect to SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, connection

I found about a dozen questions like this, read them all, but still can't find the problem.

I have a dedicated server running SQL Server 2008 R2 express. I enabled TCP/IP, added firewall exceptions, enabled mixed authentication, started SQL Browser.

I can connect to this database server from my home computer.

But from my work computer, I can't.
I can, however, connect to RDP, I can telnet 1433 and get a response.
I tried connecting from work to another sql server 2008 r2 and worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using sql server auth, or integrated windows auth?

If you can telnet, another thing to do, on the problem client, is to specify the port when connecting in SQL Management Studio:

< remote computer >,1433

Lastly, check the errorlog of the sql server. It will say something like "listening on port ###"  Make sure that SQL is really listening on 1433 (and not something else...)

Comment: I connect using sql server auth. The port sql server is listening to is 1433. If I put "name\instance,1433", it's working!!! Thanks a lot man!